# Dell Gateway 3001 with Ubuntu Core adduser with --system error

Tags: dell, ubuntu-core

I am trying to make the first steps in installing AWS IoT Greengrass to Dell Gateway 3001 via SSH connection. First I need to create an extrauser with --system flag but this fails as you can see below. I am able to create the user without --system though.

Ubuntu Core 16,
Kernel version: 4.4.0-150-generic

```
root@dell:/home/admin# sudo adduser --extrausers --system ggc_user
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("C.UTF-8").
Adding system user `ggc_user' (UID 111) ...
Adding new user `ggc_user' (UID 111) with group `nogroup' ...
usermod: user 'ggc_user' does not exist
adduser: `/usr/sbin/usermod -p * ggc_user' returned error code 6. Exiting.
root@dell:/home/admin#
```

Oh and by the way it does add new line with this username to **/var/lib/extrausers/passwd** even though the procedure gives an error. And I cannot delete this user with `sudo userdel --extrausers ggc_ucer` it again says that user does not exist. I need to manually remove the line from the file if I want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the user with `useradd` command instead of `adduser`:

First create group: `groupadd --extrausers --system ggc_group`

and then the user: `useradd --extrausers --system -g ggc_group ggc_user`

So I think the first step is now done :D

This answer helped me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt